# Cannot delete file with send2trash

Tags: python, pypdf

```
import PyPDF2, os, sys, send2trash,pathlib


def encrypt(filename, password):
    with open(filename, "rb") as readfile:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(readfile)
        writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        if not reader.isEncrypted:
            for page in range(reader.numPages):
                writer.addPage(reader.getPage(page))
        else:
            print(f"{filename} is encrypted")
            return None
    with open(f"{filename.split('.')[0]}_encrypted.pdf", "wb") as writefile:
        writer.encrypt(password)
        try:
            writer.write(writefile)
        except OSError as e:
            print(f"File write error {e}")
            return None
    with open(f"{pathlib.Path(filename).parent}\{pathlib.Path(filename).stem}_encrypted.pdf", "rb") as checkfile:
        result = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(checkfile).decrypt(password)
    if result != 0:
        try:
            send2trash.send2trash(filename)
            print(f"file {filename} was deleted after encrypted file verification")
            return "Done"
        except OSError as e:
            print(f"Delete error: {e}, filename: {filename}")
    else:
        print("Encrypted file %s was not verified so original file %s was not deleted" % (f"{filename.split('.')[0]}_encrypted.pdf", filename))
        return None


def decrypt(filename, password):
    with open(filename, "rb") as readfile:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(readfile)
        writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        if not reader.isEncrypted:
            print(f"{filename} is not_encrypted")
            return None
        else:
            result = reader.decrypt(password)
            if result == 0:
                print(f"{filename} was not decrypted with password: {password}")
                return None
            else:
                for page in range(reader.numPages):
                    writer.addPage(reader.getPage(page))
                try:
                    with open(f"{filename}_decrypted.pdf", "wb") as writefile:
                        writer.write(writefile)
                except OSError as e:
                    print(f"File write error {e}")
                    return None
                return "Done"


# password = sys.argv[1]
# option = sys.argv[2]
password = "test"
option = "decrypt"
if option not in ["encrypt", "decrypt"]:
    sys.exit(f"Wrong option, option provided is {option}, supposed to be encrypt or decrypt")
folder_path = os.path.abspath(input("Please enter the path"))
if os.path.exists(folder_path):
    for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        pdfs = filter(lambda x: str(x).lower().endswith(".pdf"), files)
        for file in pdfs:
            filename = os.path.join(folder, file)
            reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename, "rb"))
            encrypt(filename, password) if option == "encrypt" else decrypt(filename, password)
else:
    print(f"{folder_path} doesnt exist, exiting")
    sys.exit(f"{folder_path} not found")
```

Hello! The code above doesnt delete the .pdf files with send2trash.

Files seems to be closed, if i copy encrypt function to another file and run it separately - it delete the file provided - no problem. But in this script i get [win32] None errors - it just refuse to delete any file.

Can anyone kindly point at the point i'm missing? Thanks alot !

PS It supposed to go through folder(subfolders), look for .pdf files and encrypt/decrypt them.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, sorry :P

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename, "rb"))